# Using Jest to mock AJAX requests for React

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I’m building a React component which, when mounted, gets data from the server via AJAX.

I’m trying (and failing) to mock the AJAX call in Jest and am wondering if I’m just misunderstanding how mocking in Jest really works?

My file structure is:

- index.js
- index.test.js
- requests.js
- __mocks__

  - requests.js

The component (`index.js`) makes the call via `requests.js`, which uses Axios to get data from the server. `requests.js` is mocked inside the `__mocks__` folder.

As can be seen below in the test file `index.test.js`, I’m using `getSpy` to detect if the `requests.getData` function is called. It never is. I should add that I’ve also tried to get the component to simply render some of the data from the `getData` function response, and then, in the test file, run `console.log(ListWrapper.debug());` to see whether the data is rendered in the test. Again, it never is.

Just wondering if anyone can spot where I’m going wrong, or if I’m just getting the wrong end of the stick?

**index.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import List from './index';
import expect from 'expect';

import requests from './requests';

jest.mock('requests');

describe('Renders list', () => {
    const getSpy = jest.spyOn(requests, 'getData');

    const ListWrapper = mount(
        <ListWrapper />
    );

    console.log(ListWrapper.debug());

    it('should fetch currencies', () => {
        expect(getSpy).toBeCalled();   
    });
});
```

**__mocks__/requests.js**

```
module.exports = {
    getData: () => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            resolve({
               [
                    {
                        id: 1,
                        name: 'Bob Smith',
                        age: 32
                    }
                ]
            });
        });

    }
};
```

**index.js (shortened)**

```
/**
 * List component
 */
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import * as requests from './requests’;
function List(props) {

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

   /**
     * Get data from server
     */
   const getCurrencies = useCallback(() => {
      r4_uiTools.loadingAnimation.show();
      requests
          .getData()
          .then((response) => {
              setData(response);
          })
          .catch(error) {
              //...
          }

   /**
     * Get data when first mounting component
     */
    useEffect(() => {
        getData();
    }, [getData]);

  return(
   <>
    /* ... */
    {data[0].name}
   </>
  );
```

**requests.js (shortened)**

```
import axios from 'axios';

const getData = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const url = `/MyURL/`;
        axios
            .get(url)
            .then((response) => {
                resolve(response);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                reject(error);
            });
    });
};

export { getData };
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your `useEffect` look like this?

```
useEffect(() => {
    getCurrencies();
}, []);
```

Also, what is `ListWrapper` in your `index.test.js`? Is it a typo and should be `List`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are mocking the call and returning the Promise you will have to make your it block async

Also please put the mount inside the it block otherwise you have to make your describe async

```
describe('Renders list', () => {
    ...
    ...
    it('should fetch currencies', async () => {
        expect(getSpy).toBeCalled();   
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your jest.mock for request seems incorrect. If its not a node_module, it should point to the path just like your import:
`jest.mock('./requests');`

You also won't need a spy now since jest.mock mocks all the exports by './request`. If it was me, I would write the test like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import List from './index';
import expect from 'expect';

import requests from './requests';

jest.mock('./requests', () => {    // Path instead of name when mocking own modules
    return {
        default: {
            getData: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue('some value')    // explicit mock
        },
        // ... any other exports you'd wanna mock 
    };
});

describe('Renders list', () => {

    const ListWrapper = mount(
        <ListWrapper />
    );

    console.log(ListWrapper.debug());

    it('should fetch currencies', () => {
        expect(requests.getData).toBeCalled();  // Directly check on getData since it should point to a mock function   
    });
});
```

Comment: Why we need to return an object with attribute `default` in here? 
Just only `({ getData: jest.fn() })` is fine with this case.

Comment: Not sure if it would. It would probably work if getData is also exported as a named export, but if its only exported through the default export, then I guess it wouldn't. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you should choose `spyOn` or `jest.mock` to do that.
With `jest.mock`, it should be :

```
jest.mock('./requests', () => ({ 
        getData: jest.fn(),
    }));
```

And if you want to handle response data when call this. You must to use `wait` from `@testing-library/react`. You can read more at [here](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async)